# Calculate key from AES 128 encrypted message and cleartext message

Tags: encryption, aes

Is it possible to calculate the key from a AES 128 encrypted message when having the cleartext message?

Comment: Are looking for answer "Yes" or "No"?

Comment: Yes. You could try all the possible 128 bit keys on the clear text until you get your encrypted message. However, you should leave the job to your sons for many years to come... Probably the entire universe will end sooner :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography, without involving programming.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is twofold:

- No, there is not practical known way to do this
- Yes, there is the theoretical method: trying all the possible keys (but it will take too much time, that's why it's only a theoretical approach)

Comment: **If** the key was randomly generated. Given the amount of badly generated keys on SO, that's certainly not a given. Performing a brute force on a repeated or zero padded ASCII/UTF-16 encoded password may already break a lot of implementations.

Answer (score 0):

No, besides a brute force attack [which will be marginally easier if you know the plain text](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks), there is no known way to calculate the key even if you know both the encrypted text and the plain text.